# Cannot see On Hold column in Views 3

Tags: drupal, contacts, drupal-views

I am trying to create a view in Drupal listing all contacts marked as 'on hold' due to their email bouncing.

I am unable to find this 'on hold' field for selection in Views. Is this by design or is there some fault with my install.
If this is by design, is there a way to show this in Views so I can complete this 'report'?

[image]

Comment: Hi Mark, what version of CiviCRM, Drupal and Views 3 are you using?

Comment: Using CiviCRM 4.6.4 and Drupal 7.41. Views 7.x-3.11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the difference maker here is the [CiviCRM Entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_entity) module.  I have two Civi installs, one with it installed and one without.  The install that has CiviCRM Entity has "CiviCRM Email: On Hold" as a field, just like Catorghans' answer indicates.  The install that does not have the module only has the Email fields listed in your screenshot.

If you are able to install the module, Mark, I think you will find your solution.  It is an excellent module that exposes a significant number of data fields to Drupal and Views.  Out of the box only certain fields are exposed to Drupal as usable fields.

Comment: I installed the CiviCRM Entity module on Friday last week to find that my install slowed down significantly. It may be unrelated, but after uninstalling our system went back to 'normal'. As I have had no time to properly look at why/if the entity module caused this, I will not be using it. Not to say that won't change in future. I have opted to go down the route of custom report in CiviCRM though that may be a bit messy come time to upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

I see it under Email..

CiviCRM Email: On Hold